# the flutter secure storage could not fetch value putted before in macos platform

Tags: flutter

I am using this code to write the login info into flutter secure storage when login success in macos desktop app:

```
 static void saveAuthInfo(Response response, String username, String password) {
    Map result = response.data["result"];
    String accessToken = result["accessToken"];
    String refreshToken = result["refreshToken"];
    String registerTime = result["registerTime"];
    SecureStorageUtil.putString("username", username);
    SecureStorageUtil.putString("password", password);
    SecureStorageUtil.putString("accessToken", accessToken);
    SecureStorageUtil.putString("refreshToken", refreshToken);
    SecureStorageUtil.putString("registerTime", registerTime);
  }
```

the flutter secure storage version was 5.0.1 right now which I am using current. But when I tried to read the value, the returned result value was null.

```
static Future<AppUser> currentUser() async {
    String? userName = await SecureStorageUtil.getString("username");
    String? registerTime = await SecureStorageUtil.getString("registerTime");
    AppUser user = new AppUser(phone: userName, registerTime: registerTime);
    return user;
  }
```

the `SecureStorageUtil` class look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorageUtil{

  static FlutterSecureStorage _preferences = FlutterSecureStorage();

  static Future<String?> getString (String key, {String defValue = ''}) {
    return _preferences.read(key:key) ;
  }

  static Future<void> putString(String key, String value) {
    return _preferences.write(key:key, value:value);
  }

  static Future<void> delString(String key) {
    return _preferences.delete(key:key);
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to make the flutter secure storage put and fetch value? I could not use the 5.0.2 version because this version of flutter sececure storage could not compile in android(I tried the version 5.0.2 still did not work).

Comment: same issue here. do you solve it?

Comment: seems a bug, I did not know new version of this lib fix this problem.@ch271828n I downgrade the version to old.